# How to control nThread in fread() when used in lapply loop?

Tags: r, multithreading, data.table, lapply

I'm using fread() from package "data.table" to import a list of .csv files.
As they are big files, I would like to use the nThread option of fread() to use all 16 threads of my CPU.

My original line is

```
L <- lapply(files.to.read, data.table::fread)
```

I tried this:

```
L <- lapply(files.to.read, data.table::fread, nThread=16)
```

It reads the files just fine but seems to ignore the "nThread" argument. 
How can I pass nThread=16 in my fread() function in lapply?

Comment: How do you know it ignores `nThread` argument? How will you know if it is using all the threads to it's full potential?

Comment: Unless you have massive files, I don't think `fread` is your bottleneck. I've recently used `fread` with a really large file where import actually took relevant time (about 20 seconds with four cores) and I would have quickly exhausted my 32 GB RAM if I imported several of these with code like yours. Also, don't use all cores of your CPU. Leave some for your OS and other software to avoid too much load shuffling.

Comment: '*seems*' is too vague.

Comment: I suspect reading from disk or the network is the bottleneck, not the CPU.

Comment: @Ronak_Shah -> I'm monitoring usage of my threads with a sys monitors

Comment: @Roland & Ian_Campbell -> I could import all of them by using fread() separately for each and all 16 cores were used for each. Memory is no problem on my workstation. You're probably right about core # though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like a lambda function. This should work:

```r
L <- lapply(files.to.read, function(x) data.table::fread(x, nThread=16))
```

Comment: Not so. You should inform yourself about the `...` in `help("lapply")`.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment. I have used this approach many times and it worked out. But, since you seem to be an expert, could you please suggest an alternative way?

Comment: Your approach is fine. The first sentence of your answer is wrong. OP's code is fine too (and the preferable approach).

Comment: This approach worked for me. @Roland -> I did not understood what was wrong in the first phrase?